# How to reproduce url encoding in form GET request, from javascript, when accents and such are involved?

Tags: javascript, encoding, forms

Say I have a simple form like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="search">
      <form method="GET" action="/super-action">
        <input type="text" name="q" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

with an input like: `@tags "Cinéma Whatever"`

a form GET request results in a url that looks like: `/super-action?q=%40tags+"Cinéma+Whatever"`

Now I want to reproduce that with javascript in location.hash, with a pound sign instead of a slash, like: `/super-action#q=%40tags+"Cinéma+Whatever"`

But with the available functions, I get there results:

- escape(input): `@tags%20%22Cin%E9ma%20Whatever%22`
- encodeURI(input): `@tags%20%22Cin%C3%A9ma%20Whatever%22`
- encodeURIComponent(input): `%40tags%20%22Cin%C3%A9ma%20Whatever%22`
- $(form).serialize(), without q=: `%40tags+%22Cin%C3%A9ma+Whatever%22`

The question: How can I make an input value, like `@tags "Cinéma Whatever"`, look like what a form GET request would do: `%40tags+"Cinéma+Whatever"` using javascript?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want, the GET URL has a `?` while the string you'd like to make has a `#` in its place. Is it correct? You'd like to have the same string you'd have with a GET request but with the `?` replaced by `#`?

Comment: If you're willing to add a js library to your page, I may have a solution. I'd like to know if you want your encoded URL string to have a interrogation mark or a number sign first though.

Comment: @Fabricio: What I am trying to achieve is a search form that works both with ajax and without, using the same query string in the url with a (#) or a (?). That way if someone bookmarks a url with the hash (#) and comes back, I fetch the search result with javascript by passing whatever is after that hash to the server with a (?).

It might still work if special characters like "é" is "%E9", php might probably convert it on the server side. But I was hoping I could use the same conversion form GET does.

Comment: A js library would be fine! And no i don't need an interrogation mark instead of the number sign. The value after the (#) sign might contain a question mark but just like form GET does, ? should be converted to %3F.

Comment: My bad, I deleted my answer as I didn't see you wanted the `é` and `"` characters un-encoded as well. So which characters do you want encoded actually? Just the `@` and white-space are encoded in your example string.

Comment: I'll update my question with the jquery serialize! As for which characters I want encoded? Any characters a form GET submit would encode, no more, no less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [RFC 1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), `/super-action?q=%40tags+"Cinéma+Whatever"` is not valid inside an URL:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>      reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>      unencoded within a URL.

That means that you *can't* produce a valid URL with that substring in it. You **must** encode the special characters `"` and `é`, otherwise the resulting string is not a URL.

The reason why you *think* this is valid might be that your browser plays tricks on you: It could be displaying the URL in partially encoded form to make it easier to read in the address bar. Try using a protocol analyzer like Wireshark to inspect the *actual* URL path sent across the network.

**UPDATE:** I quickly confirmed this, the HTTP header sent in reaction to a form submit is the following:

```
GET /?q=%40tags+%22Cin%C3%A9ma+Whatever%22 HTTP/1.1
```

So it is first UTF-8 encoded and then URL encoded.

Comment: You are right, both google chrome and firefox are playing tricks on me . If I just select the url and copy it (CTRL-C), when I paste it anywhere else the `"` and `é` characters are both encoded. Thanks